# Perform Some Action if Azure Release Pre-deployment Approval is Rejected

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline defined in Azure DevOps. Pre-deployment approval has been configured in order for the release to be completed.

If approval is rejected, I want to perform some action, maybe run a Python script.

How can I achieve this, within the pipeline itself or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using Service Hooks ([Integrate with service hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops), [Create a service hook subscription programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/create-subscription?view=azure-devops)):

[image]